# MATLAB remove lead and lag data from variable

Tags: matlab, data-processing

I am working in a MATLAB loop with data variables (in column form) that are pulled in from excel files.  Each iteration of the loop opens a new file and repeats its process. Inside each file, I have data collected with an electronic sensor.  The sensor collects 10 cycles of data but has lead and lag values surrounding the collection period. What I want to do is isolate the collection period, removing the lead and lag data.

Unfortunately this is not force data where the lead and lag values would simply be consistent zeros making them easy to identify and remove.  Within a variable the lead values are consistent, but between variables and between files the lead values change, so I cannot set the code to look for a single, specific value. Also, the sensor does not finish where it starts so I cannot use the lead values to ID where the lag values start.

For the lead values I have set the code to read the first value of the variable and find the point where the sensor exceeds the acceptable bounds of noise/error to signify that cycling has begun:

```
lead = variable(1,1);
for i = 1:length(variable);
    if variable(i,1) >= variable(1,1)+.001 || variable(i,1) <= variable(1,1)-.001;
        cycledata = varaible(i:end,1);
        break;
    end;
end;
```

I realize this is crude and cumbersome and can't help but think there is a better way to identify the start of a cycle.  Also, I'm not really certain how to handle the lag data on the back end. Any tips / help would be appreciated.  Thanks.